# Implementing a failure handler form for Spring 4 + Spring Security 3.2.5 (no XML)

Tags: spring, spring-security

After trying to loggin in the application and receiving a CredentialsExpiredException, how to present a change password form? How to support additional parameters such new password and confirmation?

Answer (score 0):

1. Configure your WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation class as:

   ```
   http.
   //...
   .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/login", "/index.**").permitAll()
   //...
   .authenticationDetailsSource(req -> new CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(req))
   .failureHandler((req, res, e) -> {
       req.getSession().setAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION", e);
       res.sendRedirect((e instanceof CredentialsExpiredException) ? CHANGE : FAILURE);
   })
   //...
   ```

Where:

```
    private static final String FAILURE = "/index.html?login_error=true";
    private static final String CHANGE = FAILURE + "&change=true";
```

And:

```
    public class CustomWebAuthenticationDetails extends WebAuthenticationDetails {

    private Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();

    public CustomWebAuthenticationDetails(HttpServletRequest req) {
        super(req);
        put(req, "j_enc_np");
        put(req, "j_enc_cnp");
    }

    private void put(HttpServletRequest req, String key) {
        if (req.getParameter(key) != null && !"".equals(key)) {
            params.put(key, req.getParameter(key));
        }
    }

    public boolean isChange() {
        return !params.isEmpty();
    }

    public String get(String key) {
        return params.get(key);
    }

}
```

2. Prepare your login page for additional parameters:

   ```
   <form name="f" id="form-login" action="<c:url value="login"/>" method="post">
   <fieldset>
           <p><label for="j_enc_u"><spring:message code="app.lbl.username" /></label></p>
           <p><input type="text" id="j_enc_u" name="j_enc_u"></p>

           <p><label for="j_enc_p"><c:choose><c:when test="${param.change}"><spring:message code="app.lbl.old.password" /></c:when><c:otherwise><spring:message code="app.lbl.password" /></c:otherwise></c:choose></label></p>
           <p><input type="password" id="j_enc_p" name="j_enc_p"></p>

           <c:if test="${param.change}">
               <p><label for="j_enc_np"><spring:message code="app.lbl.new.password" /></label></p>
               <p><input type="password" id="j_enc_np" name="j_enc_np"></p>

               <p><label for="j_enc_cnp"><spring:message code="app.lbl.new.conf.password" /></label></p>
               <p><input type="password" id="j_enc_cnp" name="j_enc_cnp"></p>
           </c:if>

           <p><input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="app.lbl.validate" />"></p>
       </fieldset>
   </form>

   <c:choose>
       <c:when test="${param.login_error}">
           <div class="error-message"><c:out value="${SPRING_SECURITY_LAST_EXCEPTION.message}" /></div>
       </c:when>
   </c:choose>
   ```
3. Prepare your AuthenticationProvider customization:

   ```
   @Override
   public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

           final String username = authentication.getPrincipal().toString().trim();
           final String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString().trim();

           final String encryptedPassword = passwordEncryptor.encryptPassword(password);
           final CustomWebAuthenticationDetails cwad = (CustomWebAuthenticationDetails) authentication.getDetails();

           try {
               final SecUserStatus status =
                   (cwad.isChange()) ?
                       authenticationService.resetPassword(username, encryptedPassword, cwad.get("j_enc_np"), cwad.get("j_enc_cnp")) :
                           authenticationService.authenticate(username, encryptedPassword, cwad.getRemoteAddress());

               SecUser secUser = status.getSecUser();

               final UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                       new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                           secUser,
                           secUser.getPassword(),
                           secUser.getAuthorities());

               authenticationToken.setDetails(secUser);
               authenticationService.lastLogin(secUser.getId(), new Date());
               return authenticationToken;

           } catch (AuthenticationException e) {
               LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
               throw e;
           }
   }
   ```